# insmod to autostart

Tags: boot, dkms

I have a 3rd party software. Right now, everytime I reboot my system, I'm forced to use `insmod` manually via shell to load the modules.

I read a bit in the [Ubuntu Wiki - DKMS](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/DKMS) and found this. So, I guess this **DKMS** is state of the art right now. Just as a sidenote, I also found this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356224/how-to-load-a-custom-module-at-the-boot-time-in-ubuntu - But it seems that this isn't up to date anymore.

So, my daily routine is this:

```
cd /usr/src/gx/kernel/gxsd/
make
/sbin/insmod gxsd.ko
cd /usr/src/gx/kernel/fxmc_usb/
make
/sbin/insmod fxmc_usb.ko
cd /usr/src/gx/examples/cpp/cpd
make
```

I got the feedback from the support-team of this 3rd-party module, that this has to be done everytime I reboot. But this is not an option. I want to have it automatically started.

If I am not mistaken, the `make` parts are only needed once, right? I don't have to use `make` everytime I restart. But the `insmod`-part needs to be executed again, right?

I just installed dkms, but now I am stuck on how to add these insmod-commands to an autostart.

Comment: can you find the location of module files ... something like /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/

Comment: what do you mean? These files are stored (right now) in /usr/src/../myfile.ko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow anyone from inserting modules "automagically", use the following steps:

1. Create the following script:

```bsh
    #!/bin/sh
    # Example script for loading modules
    # This script is in answer to question http://askubuntu.com/questions/660901/insmod-to-autostart

    # Copyright (c) 2015 Fabby

    # This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
    # This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE. See the GNU General Public License for more details.
    # You DID NOT receive a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program as the license is bigger then this program.
    # Therefore, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/ for more details.

    # Note:
    #   untested as I do not have these proprietary modules.

    # Version 0.1   DD 2015/08/13   converted from manual work.
    # version 0.2   DD 2015/08/14   added sudo ls /home

    # Activate sudo with bogus command so next lines will not need password
    sudo ls /home > /dev/null

    if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then 
       read -p "You need to be a member of the im-operator group or root to be able to run this script"
       exit
    fi

    # Make statement : cd /usr/src/gx/kernel/gxsd/&&make
    # Insmod statement : /sbin/insmod gxsd.ko
    sudo /sbin/insmod /usr/src/gx/kernel/gxsd/gxsd.ko
    # Make statement : cd /usr/src/gx/kernel/fxmc_usb/&&make
    # Insmod statement : /sbin/insmod fxmc_usb.ko
    sudo /sbin/insmod fxmc_usb.ko
    # Make statement : cd /usr/src/gx/examples/cpp/cpd&&make
    # Seems superfluous, so let's skip this
```

2. Save it in `/usr/local/bin/DasSaffe_insmod.sh`
3. Execute the following command:

   ```
   chmod +x /usr/local/bin/DasSaffe_insmod.sh
   ```
4. Now we need to allow all users on this machine to load these modules, so we'll adapt the `sodoers` file:

   ```
   sudo visudo
   ```
5. Now look for the section `### Alias section ###` and then the `# Cmnd alias specification`.
6. Add the following lines:

   ```
   # Fabby: 2015-08-14 Create special operator for insmod
   InsMod_alias INSMOD_OPERATOR=/sbin/insmod, /usr/local/bin/DasSaffe_insmod.sh
   ```
7. Now look for the section:

   ```
   # Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
   %sudo           ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
   ```

and add below that:

```
    # Fabby: 2015-08-14 Allow the group "im-operator" to use certain applications
    %im-operator    ALL=CMD_OPERATOR
```

8. Add the group `im-operator` and your user to it by:

   ```
   sudo groupadd im-operator&&sudo adduser $USER im-operator
   ```
9. Go to the dash and type `startup app` and click on the sole icon there.
10. Click <kbd>Add</kbd>
11. In the `Command` field type: `DasSaffe_insmod.sh` and whatever you like in the `Name` and `Comment` field that will remind you what this is.
12. To test: reboot and just log on.

***Warning:*** I cannot test above, so you're my guinea pig. Please leave a comment whether this works or not.

If it does work, it's as easy as:

```
sudo adduser zsUserName im-operator
```

where `szUserName` is the name of the user to allow them to insert modules from that point-in-time forwards.

Comment: For some reason, startup app isn't shown in my list of results - nvm, got it

Comment: Okay, tried it, but it isn't working yet.  The error it throws: Main::GX Error occurred: No such device  [gxsd]. After typing /insmod gxsd.ko (and fxmc_usb.ko) it does work again, so I guess the script isn't running at the start?

Comment: Latest version.  Please try again and feed back.  If it would automagically work from the first go, just ☑ and ↑ and I'll be notified immediately when logging on.  **;-)** Otherwise, try pinging me in the chat room. **(old comments deleted, you should do the same thing to keep things tidy here)**